# Don't suggest visiting meta on locked posts on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, locked-posts

[image: ???]

The title says it all. Don't suggest visiting Meta when the locked post is on Meta. Instead, there could be a link to [What is a “locked” post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22228/310998).

I realize this [has already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113487/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange, but that was 5 years ago and there's still no answer on that question, so I think it's fine to bring it up again.

Comment: I mean... You *can* still visit meta; it ain't like the whole *site* is locked.

Comment: It's all very meta.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution in my mind, but effectively, the same thing that happens with locked/contested posts on Stack Overflow would happen with locked/contested posts on Meta Stack Overflow:  post another question about it on Meta to see if it was *really* necessary to lock it.

Mind you, this should only really be used sparingly; it's rare from what I've seen to have a locked discussion unless things are *really* heating up, and it's even rarer to overturn the decision unless the question still warrants community feedback.